# Finding the last digit of $103^{103^{103^{103^{103}}}}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need to find the last digit of $103^{103^{103^{103^{103}}}}$ so the value in $\mod10$. I know

\begin{align}
103^{103^{103^{103^{103}}}}&=(100+3)^{103^{103^{103^{103}}}}\\
&=100\cdot(stuff)+3^{103^{103^{103^{103}}}}\\
&=3^{103^{103^{103^{103}}}} \mod10
\end{align}

And then I am stuck. I have observed that the last digit of a power of 3 is cyclic:
$$3 \to 9 \to 7 \to 1 \to 3 \to 9 \to 7 \to\cdots$$

This means it depends on $103^{103^{103^{103}}}\mod4$.

Is this the right method? do I just need to keep doing this or is there a simpler "trick"?

Comment: Isn't the pattern for 103 modulo 4 just 1,3,1,3,1,3 so you need modulo 2, but that's just 1,1,1,1,1,1 so you're done?

Comment: Do you mean $103^{(103^{103})}$ or $(103^{103})^{103}$?

Comment: Exponents without parentheses work right to left.

Comment: indeed [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Serial_exponentiation) says the usual rule is to work from the top down

Comment: Yes, that's the best general method - see the link on **modular order reduction** in my answer.

Comment: Observing the period four sequence of remainders is a good start. See for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/955355/11619) for ideas on how to continue. Many techniques for problems like this are covered in [this mother thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619) and the close to 200 threads linked to it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen wow thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $103=-1\pmod4$, and $-1$ to any odd power is $-1$.

**Edit:** Full answer: once you arrive at $3^{103^{103^{103^{103}}}}$, you can take the exponent mod 4, like you suggested. Drawing from my hint, we have $103^{103^\text{positive int}}=(-1)^{\text{odd number}}=-1=3\pmod 4$, since the exponent $103^\text{positive int}$ is an odd number. So your answer is $3^3=7\pmod{10}$. The last digit is $7$.

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: odd to any power is odd @aradarbel10$ in fact parity doesn't chsnge under exponentiation.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.

Your observed pattern can be explained by $3^4=81\equiv1\pmod{10}$.

---

$103^{103}\equiv3^3\equiv3\pmod{4}$, so $103^{103^{103}} \equiv103^3\equiv3^3\equiv7\pmod{10}$.

$103^{103^{103}}\equiv3^3\equiv3\pmod4,$ so $103^{103^{103^{103}}}\equiv103^3\equiv3^3\equiv7\pmod{10}.$

Can you observe another pattern now?

Comment: Can't use that $103\equiv 1$ mod $(2)$?

Comment: why is 103^103≡3^3? am I allowed to change the exponent according to the (mod 10)?

Comment: @aradarbel10:  $103^{103}\equiv 3^{103}=(3^4)^{25}3^3\equiv3^3$; when working modulo $10$, reduce the exponent modulo $4$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner and, sorry for asking, is $103^7$ because of the $103^{103^{103}}=103^{100\cdot(\cdots)+7}$ ?

Comment: Don't be sorry, @aradarbel10; I think I made a mistake there and have edited to correct now

Answer (score 0):

$\color{#0a0}{k\ \rm odd},\ (a,10)\!=\!1\overset{\rm Euler}\Rightarrow\bmod 10\!:\ a^{\large\color{#c00} 4}\equiv 1\,\overset{\rm\color{#90f}{MOR}}\Rightarrow\, a^{\large (4n-1)^{\Large k}}\!\!\equiv a^{\large (\overbrace{4n-1)^{\Large k}\bmod\color{#c00} 4}^{\!\!\!\!\!\Large \equiv\ \,\color{#0a0}{(-1)^{k}\  \equiv}\,\ \LARGE\color{#0a0}3 }}\!\equiv a^{\large \color{#0a0}3}$

by [Euler's $\phi$ Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) combined with $\,\rm\color{#90f}{MOR}= \,$ [Modular Order Reduction.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242)

The OP is the special case $\, a = 103 = 4n\!-\!1,\,\ k = 103^{103^{103}}\! $ (or any odd integer)